# How can I find a Python script inside a encrypted and corrupted disk image?

Tags: file-recovery, filesystem-corruption

My encrypted SSD got corrupted, so I took an image of it using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). This was on a Windows 10 machine.

If I have the password for the encryption, is there any way to recover data from this image, or is it gone forever?

Comment: I swear I saw this exact same question and commented on it. Did you just delete original question as ask exact same thing again?

Comment: "My SSD got corrupted" - That's an extremely vague description. Also, does DMDE 'see' any data at all (in partition tab > advanced > now scroll through hex view)? What actually was file system, was bitlocker running, etc. .. so many questions ..

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - I have tried to re-ask the question, since the previous question was closed.

Comment: Perhaps it was closed because it's such a poorly asked question that lacks any info to go on?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - Why didn't you [edit] your original question so it could be reopened? Asking a question, then having it closed and then deleting it, is exactly what you should avoid doing.  You are not allowed to ask the same question, after it's be closed, your (presumably) close deleted should instead be edited, so it can be reopened.

Comment: @Ramhound - I feel like this is a different enough question to warrant asking it. My previous question was very general, with very many options of the answer, which is presumably why the File Recovery Wiki was suggested. This question one is more specific, and should give more focused answers.

Comment: Could be encrypted data. Does all data look this 'dense'? No blocks of zeros anywhere?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - Were you using FDE? I am not the only person to have asked this question.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes! OMG yes. I had totally forgotten that this is an encrypted disk. No wonder it all looks like gibberish. OK, so my question should really be: "How can I decrypt a corrupted encrypted disk image?"

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - You can't actually decrypt a corrupted blob of encrypted data.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - OK, I've re-asked the question again, now that I remembered that it's encrypted.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - You failed to mention what operating system you had installed.

Answer (score 3):

### Repair-bde

Accesses encrypted data on a severely damaged hard disk if the drive was encrypted by using BitLocker. Repair-bde can reconstruct critical parts of the drive and salvage recoverable data as long as a valid recovery password or recovery key is used to decrypt the data. If the BitLocker metadata data on the drive has become corrupt, you must be able to supply a backup key package in addition to the recovery password or recovery key.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff829851(v=ws.11)

Example usage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8ezF49Mfpc

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. I got the message: "ERROR: The input volume has suffered damages to critical information related to the decryption key. Please try the -KeyPackage option to specify a key package. The volume may not be recoverable."

Answer (score 0):

## Basics

> My encrypted SSD got corrupted, so I took an image of it using TestDisk. This was on a Windows 10 machine.

No, you did not take an image of your SSD but of a partition on your SSD. Testdisk only supports taking images of single partitions.

First of all, for your Python script search you need an access to a decrypted version of your disk.

## Step one:

Duplicate your corrupted disk using ddrescue to have your data on a healthy disk.

## Step two:

Remove Disk encryption or export a virtual decrypted drive

> If I have the password for the encryption, is there any way to recover data from this image, or is it gone forever?

Modern disk encryption software (Truecrypt, Veracrypt, LUKS, Bitlocker and others) uses your password only as a key to a vault on your disk that stores the key used for encryption and decryption.

When removing your disk encryption you should use a second copy of your faulty source in case it is not possible to export the decrypted information to another drive.

If the vault is dammaged, you cannot access the decrypted content of your disk anymore. The examples of disk encryption above provide you with the possibility to export the locked vault information to a secure other place to ensure that you can decrypt even a dammaged disk where the vault is affected by dammage.

## Step three:

Search for the Python script

`Case 1:` Navigation through the folder tree is possible

Use a shell like Windows Explorer or others.

`Case 2:` Navigation through the folder tree is not possible

Try out a commercial software that is able to evaluate the remains of dammaged metadata on your file system.

OR

Try out a file carver like Photorec (contained in the Testdisk software package). It contains pre-defined fingerprints to search for Python files.